# Are there any counterexamples which show that $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ cannot imply $X,Y$ is not necessarily independent?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I know that if $X,Y$ are independent, then $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ holds. But the reverse is not true. I'd like to know that are there any examples to show the fact?

Comment: Please edit title to match your actual question. It's hard to say what if anything your title is asking but it can't be what you meant to ask

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent random variables such that $X$ takes $0$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$ each and $Z$ takes $-1$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$ each.

Then $XZ$ and $X$ satisfy the condition you have given but are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a random variable that takes value $0$ with probability $1/2$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. Let $T$ be a random variable, independent of $X$, that takes the value $−1$ with probability $1/2$, and takes the value $1$ with probability $1/2$. And let $Y = XT$.

We have that $E[X]=1/2$ and $E[Y] =0$. I'll leave it to you to check that $E[XY] = [X^2 T]=0$, which would mean $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$.

Now the question is, are $X$ and $Y$ independent? What's the probability that $Y=1?$ What's the probability that $Y=1$ given that $X=0?$ Conditioning on $X$ affects $Y$, so they're not independent.